# When is $f^*:H^1(G_K,N)\to H^1(G_K,M)$ injective?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

et $K$ be a number field and $G_K$ be a absolute Galois group of $K$.

Let $f:N \to M$ be an injetion of map between $G_K$modules.

Then, induced map $f^*$ between Galois Cohomology, $f^*:H^1(G_K,N)\to H^1(G_K,M)$ is not necessalily injective.

What kind of condition on $f$ implies $f^*$ is also injetive ?

For example, if $f$ is inclusion as a set, is $f^*$ injection ?

**P.S.**

Thanks to Mathmo123, I heard $Kerf^* \cong \frac{(M/N)^{G_K}}{M^{G_K}/N^{G_K}}$ still I don't understand why this holds.

I don't understand why this isomorphism holds.
Short exact sequence $0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to 0$ induces long exact sequence
$0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to H^1(G_K,N) \to H^1(G_K,M)\to・・・$.

Comment: What is the relation between $R$ and the number field $K$? Do $N$ and $M$ carry actions of $G_K$?

Comment: I'm assuming that $M, N$ are $G_K$ modules? Then your question is just the long exact sequence in Galois cohomology. The kernel is isomorphic to $\frac{(M/N)^{G_K}}{M^{G_K}/N^{G_K}}$, where $(\cdot)^{G_K}$ denotes the points of $(\cdot)$ fixed by $G_K$.

Comment: So the answer to your last question is no. I guess you might have seen this in the context of elliptic curves? Let $E/\mathbb Q$ be an elliptic curve, $K = \mathbb Q$, $M = E(\overline{\mathbb Q})$ and $N = E(\overline{\mathbb Q})[n]$ for some $n$. Then $f^*$ is injective if and only if $E(\mathbb Q) / nE\mathbb (\mathbb Q) = 0$.

Comment: @Mathmo123.  Thank you very much. My interest is in $M=E[2]$, $N=E[\phi]$, where $\phi$ is two isogeny. But if I admit your $Ker$, it's ok. But I don't understand why your isomorphism holds.Could you tell me why your isomorphism holds ?

Comment: In that case, the kernel would be $E’[\hat\phi](\mathbb Q)/\phi(E[2](\mathbb Q))$. In your long exact sequence, you need to take $G_K$ invariants for the first three factors (these are the $H^0$’s). You can then split the exact sequence: if $0\to A \to B\to C\to D\to\cdots$ is exact, then so is $0\to A/B\to C\to D\to\cdots$ and so on.

Comment: You mean, $0\to B/A \to C \to・・・$ ?  I understand the isomorphism, thank you ! If $E[2]^{G_K}=E[2]$, $Kerf=0$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry I swapped A and B. That is one sufficient condition, but it is not necessary

Comment: Re your P.S.: the long exact sequence is $0 \rightarrow N^{G_K} \rightarrow M^{G_K} \rightarrow (M/N)^{G_K} \rightarrow H^1(G_K,N) \rightarrow H^1(G_K,M) \rightarrow \ldots$.